# Is there a way to gzip a byte buffer in Java?

Tags: java, jvm, gzip, nio, bytebuffer

I have pretty huge `DirectByteBuffer` and I would like to produce a gzipped `DirectByteBuffer` from it without transferring its content to the heap.

The standard `java.util.Deflater` cannot be helpful since it operates on `byte[]` which is on-heap by definition.

Is there a way to do this in Java? Or I have to call `libzip` directly through `JNI`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with Java 11, there are

- [`Deflater.setInput(ByteBuffer input)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#setInput(java.nio.ByteBuffer))

and

- [`Deflater.deflate(ByteBuffer output)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#deflate(java.nio.ByteBuffer)) resp.
- [`Deflater.deflate(java.nio.ByteBuffer output, int flush)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#deflate(java.nio.ByteBuffer,int))

allowing to specify input and output as byte buffers. Of course, it’s implementation dependent whether this actually allows a direct off-heap processing, but a quick look into OpenJDK revealed that it has a `native` method for the buffer-to-buffer processing.

Technically, it’s not GZip, unless you’re also writing the artifacts of that file format, but I suppose, you’re mainly interested in the compression rather than the file format.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. May I ask you about the previous version of JDK? I currently use JDK8 since Scala does not work properly on JDK 9+, so it is impossible to migrate right now. So is the only solution on JDK 8 is to call libzip explicitly?

Comment: I don’t know of any earlier solution. So you have to call libzip directly or update the JDK. I think, knowing that there will be a simple solution in the current version discourages from spending too much effort on interfacing with native libraries in an older version…